# Form action button does not submit

Tags: html, forms

I have been trying to make a form where customers can specify their orders and it will be sent to my mail id. But when I click on submit, instead of loading **mailorder.php** it runs **mail.php** a file that I had set up for sending a different form data, any idea why this might be happening? 
Below is the code I am using.

```
<form id="myForm" action="mailorder.php" method="post" class="contact-form">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="fname" placeholder="Enter Employee name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Employee name'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="sname" placeholder="Enter shop name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter shop name'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="email" placeholder="Enter Shop Owner's Contact Number" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Shop Owner's Contact Number'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="saddress" placeholder="Enter Shop address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Shop address'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div><div class="col-lg-10">
                        <p></p>
                        <h3 style="color:#333;">Please fill product details below:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input name="itemone" placeholder="Enter Item 1" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Item 1'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input name="colorone" placeholder="Enter Colour" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Colour'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input name="qtyone" placeholder="Quantity" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Quantity'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10 d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <button class="primary-btn white-bg d-inline-flex align-items-center mt-20"><span class="mr-10">Send Message</span><span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span></button> <br>
                </div>
                <div class="alert-msg"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: set button type `submit`

Answer (score 1):

button type missing

```html
<form id="myForm" action="mailorder.php" method="post" class="contact-form">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="fname" placeholder="Enter Employee name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Employee name'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="sname" placeholder="Enter shop name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter shop name'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="email" placeholder="Enter Shop Owner's Contact Number" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Shop Owner's Contact Number'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input name="saddress" placeholder="Enter Shop address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Shop address'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div><div class="col-lg-10">
                        <p></p>
                        <h3 style="color:#333;">Please fill product details below:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input name="itemone" placeholder="Enter Item 1" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Item 1'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input name="colorone" placeholder="Enter Colour" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Colour'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <input name="qtyone" placeholder="Quantity" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Quantity'" class="common-input mt-20" required="" type="number">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-10 d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <button type="submit" class="primary-btn white-bg d-inline-flex align-items-center mt-20"><span class="mr-10">Send Message</span><span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span></button> <br>
                </div>
                <div class="alert-msg"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
```